# Problems with Datepicker format in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to format my datepicker but does not work. Nothing at all happens. Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script src="myJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text" />
```

In my JS-file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            monthNames: ["Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Sön", "Mån", "Tis", "Ons", "Tors", "Fre", "Lör"],
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Comment: that should not be a reason for your problem but you are using jquery's on DOM ready twice , `$(function(){...})` is equivalent for `$( document ).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5A6Su/), I just copied your code and removed your myJS.js, and it works well.
So probably problem is in your myJS.js file

Comment: I'm getting no errors. The problem is that nothing happens at all

Comment: Paulitto, I want to keep myJS.js since I'll put lots of other code in it later.

Comment: what I was trying to say is that most likely problem is in that "other" code, because what you posted in question actually works

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
 monthNames: ["Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Sön", "Mån", "Tis", "Ons", "Tors", "Fre", "Lör"],
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1,
        });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">


</body>
</html>
```

Check this